# Notifications being removed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsnotifications

I have a model object and a window controller. I would like them to be able to communicate via notifications. I create both during the App Delegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method. I add the observers after the window controller's window is loaded, like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    WordSetWindowController* windowController = [[WordSetWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"WordSetWindowController"];

    model = [[WordSetModel alloc] init];

    NSWindow*   window = windowController.window;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:windowController
                                             selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
                                                 name:kNotification_GeneratingPairs
                                               object:model];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:windowController
                                             selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
                                                 name:kNotification_ProcessingPairs
                                               object:model];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:windowController
                                             selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
                                                 name:kNotification_UpdatePairs
                                               object:model];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:windowController
                                             selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
                                                 name:kNotification_Complete
                                               object:model];

    [model initiateSearch];
}
```

The `-iniateSearch` method kicks off some threads to do some processor-intensive calculations in the background. I'd like those threads to send notifications so I can update the UI while processing is occurring. It looks like this:

```
- (void)initiateSearch;
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotification_GeneratingPairs
                                                        object:self];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // ... do the first part of the calculations ...

        // Notify the UI to update
        self->state = SearchState_ProcessingPairs;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotification_ProcessingPairs
                                                                object:self];
        });

        // ... Do some more calculations ...

        // Notify the UI that we're done
        self->state = SearchState_Idle;
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotification_Complete
                                                                object:self];
        });

    });
}
```

The first notification works properly, but none of the notifications that happen in the `dispatch_async()` call ever cause the notification handler to be called. I've tried calling `-postNotificationName::` both on the background thread and the UI thread (both by using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),...)` and by calling `-performSelectorOnMainThread:::`) and neither had any effect.

Curious, I added a call via an `NSTimer` that waits 5 seconds after the big `dispatch_async()` call at the end of `-initiateSearch:` and found that even though that all occurs on the main UI thread, it also does not fire the notification handler. If I simply call `postNotification:::` immediately after the `dispatch_async()` call returns, it works properly, though.

From this, I'm concluding that the observers are somehow getting removed from the notification center, despite the fact that my code never calls -removeObserver:. Why does this happen, and how can I either keep it from happening or where can I move my calls to `-addObserver` so that they aren't affected by this?

Comment: Is the `kNotification_GeneratingPairs` notification fired? You receive it in your `handleNotification:` function?

Comment: Yes, it fires and  the `handleNotification:` function is called. If I move it to be the first line inside the `dispatch_async()` it does not fire, even if it is re-disptached to the main UI thread. It seems as if something about `dispatch_async()` is causing the observers to get removed. However, if I move it to be just after the `dispatch_async()` call returns it fires, unless it's on a timer and waits for a few seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is suspect your window controller is getting deallocated.

You assign it to `WordSetWindowController* windowController`, but that reference disappears at the end of `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, and likely your window controller with it.

Since the window itself is retained by AppKit while open, you end up with an on-screen window without a controller. (Neither `NSWindow` nor `NSNotificationCenter` maintain strong references to its controller/observers.)

The initial notification works because those are posted before `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` ends and/or the autorelease pool for that event is drained.

Create a strong reference to your window controller in your application delegate, store the window controller's reference there, and I suspect everything will work as advertised.

Something very similar happened to me with a window controller that was also a table delegate; the initial setup and delegate messages would work perfectly, but then later selection events mysteriously disappeared.

Comment: Yes, ARC is your friend ... until it's not, LOL